# Unable to add prices for InApp Purchase in dollar, getting option in swiss an the Developer account is of Germany

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm unable to add prices of **InAppPurchase** products in **AppStoreConnect**, as my account is of Germany I'm getting only option to add the price in Swiss.

My application is for world wide, so I want to add the amount in dollars.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In App Store connect it will be automatically converted to respective currency for respective country.

You need to set price for your base currency.

[image]

See the above image you will get an idea.